# How to get HDMI video out to work with ATI Radeon HD mobility?

Tags: ati, hdmi

I have an ATI Radeon HD mobility 5400 series, and I believe I am running the open source driver. Currently, VGA out works fine for running an external monitor. HDMI out does not work at all. xrandr does not even list an HDMI output.

I really appreciate the help. Thank you.

Comment: Alternatively you can use an mini-displayport-to-HDMI adapater, though its not the correct solution for your problem

Comment: I think I have the correct set of wires. It has to be some kind of driver issue.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)